# Delete collection elements in a JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm back on `JPA` since a very long time and I forgot the most. I have this scenario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tablea")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taba", CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  List<TableB> tableb;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tableb")
public class TableB implements Serializable {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_tablea")
  TableA taba;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_tablec")
  TableC tabc;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tablec")
public class TableC implements Serializable {
  ...
}
```

As you can see, `TableB` is an association table that I use to keep references between `TableA` and `TableC` and few more infos. As far as I add or modify `TableB` objects encapsulated in my `TableA` instance, entity manager merge the object as I expect, database is updated accordingly. Let's say I have a `TableA` object that encapsulate 3 `TableB` objects in its `tableb` attribute. I remove one of the elements in `tableb`, then I move (serialize/deserialize) the `TableA` object to the entity manager in order to do `entitymanager.merge(tableainstance)`, but when I look the database all the 3 `TableB` records are still there. I did not expect to find them, what's going wrong? I am using `JPA 2.0`, `eclipselink 2.5.0`.

Comment: You set cascade all, which cascades JPA operations persist, merge, delete and refresh to referenced entities. If you dereference a TableB entity instance, why would JPA try to delete it? I think you are expecting orphan removal, a separate feature that shouldn't be used lightly: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/

Answer (score 0):

1. Since TableB is at owning side of OneToMany relationship so remove reference to TableA from TableB.
   `tableBInstance.taba=null;`
2. Clear caches after merge.
   `entitymanager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();`